# Text Edit - Save RTFD as RTF

Tags: macos, textedit

As per my understanding the file format `RTFD` > `RTF` > `TXT` file i.e. a text file can hold a subset of content and formatting compared to RTF and similarly RTF can hold a subset of content and formatting compared to RTFD.

I can save an RTF file as TXT file by going to `Format -> Make Plain Text`. Of course I would lose some formatting because txt file can only have a subset of RTF file formatting

Similarly, I want to save an RTFD as an RTF file even though I will loose some formatting that an RTFD can support but RTF cannot. But I am not able to find an option in TextEdit to save an Untitled file as `.RTF` file. I think the content present in the untitled file has some RTFD related formatting. So when I try to do `File -> Hold option key -> Save as` then I cannot find an option to save the untitled file as RTF. How Do I save the file as .RTF file using TextEdit even though I am fine with loosing the extra formatting?

Comment: The D happens when you have attachments. Why not delete those and save again? Also, do you have an example document or a way to make a quick rtfd file - perhaps uploading a sample, someone would have a command line tool that deftly strips the attachments for you since RTF is text based and easily manipulated programmatically.

Comment: @bmike: I tried to upload .rtfd file to dropbox but dropbox is creating a zip which has a folder and inside which there is an rtf file. My rtfd file does not have any attachments so I want a simple way to convert this rtfd file to rtf file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3icdgkvqfgfpmw/convert_rtfd_to_rtf.rtfd.zip?dl=0

Comment: Your learning journey is starting well - excellent question showing how encoding, flies and folders can all be the same thing or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RTFD` format is actually a package format that allows it to have related files attached, like images. If your document has any files attached, you will not be able to save it as a straight `RTF`.

Try right clicking on your `RTFD` file and select "Show Package Contents" and you will see the contents: the "core" `RTF` file is usually named `TXT.RTF` and the *other files* also present.

You can actually grab the RTF straight out of the Package without even going through saving it manually via `TextEdit.app`.

Comment: I had invisible attachments so couldn't manually delete them - hugely appreciated.